# Computing the fundamental group of a space obtained by attaching a circle?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

the space is obtained by attaching a circle $\mathbb S^1$ to the unit disk in $\mathbb R^2$ with boundary without the center by the attaching map $f(\cos t, \sin t) = (\cos 5t, \sin 5t)$?

I have learnt how to compute the fundamental group when attaching a 2-cell to a path-connected space, but $\mathbb S^1$ is not a 2-cell. So I don't know how to deal with it. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome Math.SE! Take the [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) using $LaTeX$ syntax.

Comment: Can you describe what the attaching space looks like?

Comment: I am under the impression that if you attach the circle then you don't get more than the disk you started with.

Comment: hi pedro, I think attaching a circle to the unit disk except its center I got the disk with its boundary identified to the image of f. But I don't know how to compute its fundamental group. Is that Z/(5Z)?

Comment: oh my god I thought too much It's clearly (Z*Z)/5Z by using van-kampen therom. Thank you all!!